# Anchor tag being stripped insde a node, when using simplexml_load_string in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to get the value of a node when using simplexml_load_string. I get the value of the node fine, but for some reason the anchor tag contained within the tag gets completely stripped out, and doesn't show up.

Here is the xml:

```
<MessageAfterVoting>Thanks for voting! Here is a link to a page: <a href="/poll/result.html" >clickhere</a></MessageAfterVoting>
```

When I use simplexml_load_string to access this node (MessageAfterVoting). I get just the text

```
Thanks for voting! Here is a link to a page:
```

I'm calling the simplexml_load_string like this:

```
$PresentationContent = simplexml_load_string($pollXML);
```

Anybody have any ideas of a workaround? Preferably not using CDATA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function SimpleXmlElementAsString($simpleXmlElement)
{           
    $innerXML= '';
    foreach (dom_import_simplexml($simpleXmlElement)->childNodes as $child)
    {
        $innerXML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
    }
    return $innerXML;
}
```

So you would use it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($pollXML);
$MessageAfterVoting = $xml->MessageAfterVoting;
$PresentationContent = SimpleXmlElementAsString($MessageAfterVoting);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use CDATA then you can use html entities. Change < and > to &lt; and &gt; codes.

But CDATA is correct way.